# Three.js camera rotation order

Tags: javascript, rotation, three.js, euler-angles, gamepad-api

I'm trying to use a gamepad to rotate a camera in Three.js, using first-person-shooter style controls.

The browser detects the gamepad and recognises it's input, but the camera's order of rotation is wrong. When I rotate on the camera's local Y axis, it takes into account the local X rotation too, which is unwanted.

- What I want: http://jsfiddle.net/fYtwf/3/
- What is happening: http://jsfiddle.net/fYtwf/2/

It seems I'm having the same problem as [this guy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13261270/first-person-simulation-with-three-js-using-keyboard-arrows), but his issue was solved using Three.js r54 and I'm using r60. He set `camera.eulerOrder = "YXZ";` to get it working, but the current equivalent `camera.rotation.order = "YXZ";` doesn't seem to work for me.

I'm aware of Three.js' built-in "FirstPersonControls" class, but it's not suitable for me as it doesn't accept controller input and it would be messy to shoehorn other non-movement controls in there later. I'm also aware of gamepad.js and have no interest in using it.

Can anyone help?

My rotation code:

```
function pollGamepad()
{
    gamepad = navigator.webkitGetGamepads()[0];

    //Rotation
    if(gamepad.axes[3] > 0.20)
    {
        camera.rotateX(-gamepad.axes[3] * 0.02);
    }
    if(gamepad.axes[3] < -0.20)
    {
        camera.rotateX(-gamepad.axes[3] * 0.02);
    }

    if(gamepad.axes[2] < -0.20)
    {
        camera.rotateY(-gamepad.axes[2] * 0.02);
    }
    if(gamepad.axes[2] > 0.20)
    {
        camera.rotateY(-gamepad.axes[2] * 0.02);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The approach that [`PointerLockControls`](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/blob/master/examples/js/controls/PointerLockControls.js) uses is to create a hierarchy of objects: `yawObject` contains `pitchObject` contains `camera`. Then horizontal mouse (or joystick) movement would change the Y-rotation of the yaw object, vertical mouse (or joystick) movement would change the X-rotation of the pitch object, and the camera's rotation would stay fixed at the default `(0, 0, -1)`. This just manually simulates Euler `YXZ` ordering but it may work better for you. It does create some awkwardness if you need to get the overall rotation.

In a custom controller I wrote recently, I achieved the same result by `add()`ing the camera to a single parent object and setting the parent object's Euler order to `YXZ`. I don't remember why this worked better than setting it on the camera directly, but it did.

Comment: Thanks Icemonster, this helped a lot.

Comment: I just put my camera inside a parent object and applied all translation and yaw to that, any pitch is then applied to the camera itself and that seems to work really well, while keeping everything simple.

Comment: THANK YOU!!! I was struggling with rotation my yawObject (since 3 days). I used PointerLockControls, where my camera is parented to an 'anchor' object (a simple object 3D), so that whenever I move my mouse, the object rotates with my camera revolving around it. Then I added key press events for WASD movements, and in a requestAnimationFrame(), I updated my character mesh's positions. So now when I tried to rotate my character mesh along Y while pressing WASD keys, I could not rotate beyond this range (-90 to 90). My character was facing a gimbal lock. So I changed my anchor's euler order

Comment: Also, in newer versions of three js, the object.eulerOrder is set as object.rotation.order

Answer (score 0):

I faced this problem myself and I came up with a simple solution. Always reset camera's x rotation to zero before performing a y rotation. Then, restore x rotation. So:

```
// Rotate camera Fps style
function rotateCamera(dx,dy){
    //store previous x rotation
    var x = camera.rotation.x;

    //reset camera's x rotation.
    camera.rotateX(-x);

    //rotate camera on y axis
    camera.rotateY(dy);

    //check if we are trying to look to high or too low
    if ( Math.abs( dx + x ) > Math.Pi/2 - 0.05) {
        camera.rotateX(x);
    else
        camera.rotateX(x+dx);

    //reset z rotation. Floating point operations might change z rotation during the above operations.
    camera.rotation.z = 0;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
I pressed every button until it worked this is the code it pops out

    var controlers = [];
controlers[0] = 0;
controlers[1] = 0;
controlers[2] = 0;
controlers[3] = 0;
controlers[4] = 0;
controlers[5] = 0;
controlers[6] = 0;
controlers[7] = 0;
controlers[8] = 0;
controlers[20] = 0;
var shooting = [];
shooting[0] = 0;        
let controllerIndex = [];

window.addEventListener("gamepadconnected", (event) => {
  const gamepad = event.gamepad;
  controllerIndex[event.gamepad.index] = event.gamepad.index;
  console.log("connected");
});

window.addEventListener("gamepaddisconnected", (event) => {
  controllerIndex = [];
  console.log("disconnected");
});

function handleButtons(buttons, indexid) {
  for (let i = 0; i < buttons.length; i++) {
    var button = buttons[i];
    var buttonElement = document.getElementById(`controller-b${i}`);
    var selectedButtonClass = "selected-button";

    if (buttonElement) {
      if (button.value > 0) {
        buttonElement.classList.add(selectedButtonClass);
        buttonElement.style.filter = `contrast(${button.value * 150}%)`;
     

 } else {
        buttonElement.classList.remove(selectedButtonClass);
        buttonElement.style.filter = `contrast(100%)`;
      }
    }
  }
}

function updateStickk(elementId, leftRightAxis, upDownAxis, indexid) 
{
    const stickLeftRighta = leftRightAxis;
    const stickUpDowna = upDownAxis;

    var stickUpDown_b = ( (stickLeftRighta) * 100);

    var stickLeftRight_b = ( (stickUpDowna) * 100);



    if( stickLeftRight_b > 30  ){

    camera.translateZ(15);


    }
    if( stickLeftRight_b < -30  ){
    camera.translateZ(-15);
    }


    if( stickUpDown_b > 30  ){
    camera.translateX(15);
    }
    if( stickUpDown_b < -30  ){
    camera.translateX(-15);
    }
}

function updateStick(elementId, leftRightAxis, upDownAxis, indexid) 
{
   if( indexid != null)  
   {
           const multiplier = 25; 
           const stickLeftRight = leftRightAxis;
           const stickUpDown = upDownAxis;



     if( controlers[0] + 100 < Date.now())
     {

    camera.cameras[indexid] = camera.cameras[indexid];
    camera.target = new THREE.Vector3( 0, 0, 0  );

    var stickLeftRight_b = ( (stickLeftRight) * 100);
    var stickUpDown_b = ( (stickUpDown) * 100);

    if( stickLeftRight_b <= -100 || stickLeftRight_b >= 100 || stickUpDown_b < -10 || stickUpDown_b > 10 ){ 
    


        if(  stickUpDown_b < -10 )
        {

            if(camera.rotation.x > -25)
                    {
                        camera.rotateX(0.1) ; 
                    } 
                else 
                    {
                        camera.rotation.x = 0;
                    }

        
        }

    if( stickUpDown_b > 10  )
        {
            if(camera.rotation.x < 25)
            {
                camera.rotateX(-0.1) ; 
            } 
            else 
            {
                camera.rotation.x =  0;
            }
            
        }

        if(  stickLeftRight_b >= 100 )
        {
            if( camera.rotation.y >= -359)
            {
                camera.rotation.y -=  0.1 ;
                camera.rotation.z = 0;
                camera.rotation.x = 0 ;
            }
        }

        if( stickLeftRight_b <= -100 )
        {
            if( camera.rotation.y <= 359)
            {
                camera.rotation.y += 0.1 ;
                camera.rotation.z = 0 ;
                camera.rotation.x = 0 ;
            }
        }
           }
controlers[0] = 0; 

    }
      }
   }
    
function handleSticks(axes, indexid) 
    {
        updateStickk("controller-b10", axes[0], axes[1], indexid );
        updateStick("controller-b11", axes[2], axes[3], indexid );
    }

function gameLoop()
   {
      if (controllerIndex.length > 0)  
      { 
        for( var loop_id = 0; loop_id < controllerIndex.length; loop_id++)
        {
                const gamepad = navigator.getGamepads()[loop_id];
                gamepad.indexid = controllerIndex[loop_id];
            handleButtons(gamepad.buttons, gamepad.indexid);
                handleSticks(gamepad.axes , gamepad.indexid );
        }
       }
    requestAnimationFrame(gameLoop);
   }

gameLoop();
```